# How to change user and group from root to svnadmin for creation of new repository using collabnet rest api

Tags: perl, collabnet

Issue:

1. By Calling Collabnet RESTFUL API, the repository is getting created by user and group as “root”.
2. Permission issue to the repository will comes into picture, as i need to create server spaces (directory) inside the repository with “svnadmin” user.

The request:

```
https://< server_name:port >/csvn/api/1/repository?format=json

content:
{
  "name":"repo-name",
  "applyStandardLayout":"false",
  "applyTemplateId":2
}
```

command ussing for creating dir :

`/apps/csvn/bin/svn mkdir file:///opt/svnroot/repos/repo-name/dir -m "Test"`